# OpenGL texture format GL_R11F_G11F_B10F - choosing data type

Tags: opengl, textures

I would like to use a texture with internal format GL_R11F_G11F_B10F as a framebuffer attachment (postprocessing effects, HDR rendering). I'm not sure which data type I should chosse - glTexImage2D 8th parameter. Here are the possible options:

- GL_HALF_FLOAT
- GL_FLOAT
- GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10F_11F_11F_REV

Could you please explain based on which criteria should I choose that type ?

Comment: You choose based on the format your data is in. Where does the data for `glTexImage2D` come from?

Comment: That's a framebuffer attachment, so initially nullptr is passed as a data parameter to glTexImage2D. Then a fragment shader render to that texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format` and `type` of `glTexImage2D` instruct OpenGL how to interpret the image that you pass to that function through the `data` argument. Since you're merely allocating your texture without specifying any image (i.e. set `data = NULL`) the exact values of `format` and `type` do not matter. The only requirement for them is to be compatible with the `internalformat`, or else `glTexImage2D` will generate `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when validating the arguments.

However, since you're not specifying an image, it's best to use `glTexStorage2D` here. This function has simpler semantics and you don't need to specify `format`, `type` and `data` at all.